# Why doesn't setting the selectedValue in the Selectlist make that value highlighted in the browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlist

When I do this:

```
new SelectList(items, dataValueField, dataTextField, items.First());
```

I get a SelectList with that item selected (it is inserted as SelectedValue), but not highlighted.

What should I do to get a dropdown with a list where I decide in advance what item is selected when the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that dataFieldValue = "Id", try this:

```
new SelectList(items, dataValueField, dataTextField, items.First().Id);
```

It's looking for the value, not the item.

Comment: That did the trick and actually solved a few of my other problems with the selectlist too :)